# Django: How to set default model.charfield using enum?

Tags: django, django-models, enums

I am having an issue with trying to `migrate` across the default value shown in the model. I get the error below. I followed what was write on [here](http://anthonyfox.io/2017/02/choices-for-choices-in-django-charfields/), however, it appears they did not have the same issue.

**error message**

```
field=models.CharField(choices=[('BIG','Larger'), ('MID','Normal'), ('SMALL','Small')], 
                       default=library.models.FontSize('Normal'), 
                       max_length=10),
AttributeError: module 'library.models' has no attribute 'FontSize'
```

**model**

```
class Book(models.Model):

    class FontSize(ChoiceEnum):
        BIG = 'Larger'
        MID = 'Normal'
        SMALL = 'Small'

    #Other fields
    font_size = model.CharField(max_length=10, choices=FontSize.choices(), default=FontSize.MID)
```

**choices.py**

```
class ChoiceEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return tuple((x.name, x.value) for x in cls)
```

Comment: change the method name to something else and check

Comment: Did you mean `library.models.Book.FontSize` ?

Comment: @Exprator which method name?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Implementation, models.py

```
FONT_CHOICES = [
    ['BIG', 'Larger'],
    ['MID', 'Normal'],
    ['SMALL', 'Small'],
]

class FontSizeEnum(object):
    LARGER = 'BIG'
    NORMAL = 'MID'
    SMALL = 'SMALL'


class Book(models.Model)
    field = models.CharField(choices=FONT_CHOICES, 
                   default=FontSizeEnum.NORMAL, 
                   max_length=10)
```